# Create html tag wrapper in Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I'm new to Rails and I'd like to create a helper function that consume whatever I pass and returns wrapped element. I was trying to use something like `content_tag` / `tag` however it won't cover all of my use cases. It should create `div` and wrap it over element that I pass as an argument. In most cases it would be just nested HTML. I'm looking for something like code below that would consume anything, it would be nice if it would work with render method as well.

Helper method:

```
def helper_method(content)
  content_tag(:div, content)
end
```

in ERB file:

```
helper_method('<span><p>Something</p></span>')
```

In React I would just pass "children". How should I handle that in Rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capture the block, and pass it to `content_tag` like so:

```
def something(css_class, &block)
  content_tag(:div, class: css_class, &block)
end
```

Use it in a view like so:

```
<%= something('my-css-class') do %>
  ...your content here...
<% end %>
```

This avoids the security issues inherent with `.html_safe`.

Comment: (Sorry for being redundant as I asked the same question under second anwer).
Thanks for you answer, I'm wondering how would I pass tags with attributes set dynamically, coming from variables in .erb file. What do you think?

Comment: @viciousP helper functions are just functions, so pass them in as arguments - I'll edit the answer to give an example of this.

Answer (score 1):

You'll use exactly how you described it. You can return HTML safe strings from helpers by setting the string as [html_safe](https://apidock.com/rails/String/html_safe)

Example:

```
def helper_method content
  content_tag(:div, content.html_safe)
end
```

Note that, this can potentially introduce security issues. You don't want to call `html_safe` on user entered strings because scripts will execute. It's not really `safe` as the name suggests ;)

Read more:

- [stay-safe-while-using-html-safe-in-rails-9e368836fac1](https://product.reverb.com/stay-safe-while-using-html-safe-in-rails-9e368836fac1)
- [everything-you-know-about-html_safe-is-wrong](https://makandracards.com/makandra/2579-everything-you-know-about-html_safe-is-wrong)
- [proper use of html_safe](https://gist.github.com/joekur/73779c40c481a2f8a44f)

**For ideal approach**, use [sanitize](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper/sanitize):

```
def helper_method content
  content_tag(:div, sanitize(content))
end
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I'm wondering how would I pass tags with attributes set dynamically, coming from variables in .erb file. What do you think?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll upvote it as it also helped me understanding the solution.

Comment: I'm not sure I get this, once they are computed, you can pass it to the function as arguments. Thank you @viciousP, I hope you went with `sanitize` since it's the right approach, even if you marked another answer as correct ;)

Comment: hey @radubogdan what's your opinion on `&block`, how's that wrong?

Comment: There is no good or bad here, `&block` is part of `content_tag` attributes so somehow it makes sense to utilize that, but you do it for a different purpose (Procs). When you have a stringified HTML it doesn't make sense since holding reference to the block can be costly in terms of performance.

Comment: And @viciousP, if you like the `helper_method do .. end` approach, keep in mind that every method can `yield`. Simply replace  `sanitize(content)` with `sanitize(yield)` and then use `helper_method { <span><p>Something</p></span> }` ;)